# How can I connect a group of vms in Azure?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, azure

I have a number of Azure Linux VMs. I am able to ssh into all of them using the public azure connection info, however I am not able to ssh from one vm into another vm using the private info.

I have found that there are different gateways on the vms, and I am thinking that might be the issue.

VM 1

```
$ route -n

Destination  Gateway       Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
xx.xx.xx.16  xx.xx.xx.25   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
xx.xx.xx.24  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
yy.yy.0.0    0.0.0.0       255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
yy.yy.0.0    0.0.0.0       255.240.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0      xx.xx.xx.25   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0      xx.xx.xx.25   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

VM 2

```
$ route -n

Destination  Gateway       Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
xx.xx.xx.16  xx.xx.xx.33   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
xx.xx.xx.32  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
yy.yy.0.0    0.0.0.0       255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
yy.yy.0.0    0.0.0.0       255.240.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0      xx.xx.xx.33   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0      xx.xx.xx.33   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I've tried setting up routes on one vm to match the route on the other vm.

How can I get these vms to communicate to each other?

Edit:

Error message is:

```
ssh: connect to host xxxxxxx port 22: No route to host
```

Edit:

Turns out my virtual network was configured with an address space of 172.21.0.0/25, but there are two subnets 172.21.0.0/28 and 172.21.0.16/29.

I'm pretty sure the subnets are the issue, and I'll update once I make the subnet space match the address space.

Edit:

I created a new subnet on 172.21.0.64/26 which allows me to let all of my VMs join a single subnet.

For some reason the Azure web portal was not allowing me to attach a VM to a subnet.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to connect from one instance to another ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a private network between all your machines. An Azure virtual network (VNet) is a representation of your own network in the cloud.

Windows Azure virtual networks are deployed as an overlay network in the Windows Azure cloud and can be configured as isolated, cloud-only networks. Optionally you can easily extend your on-premises network to the cloud using virtual networking and site-to-site VPN. As it is implemented today, it is difficult to make changes to virtual networks after they have been configured, so it is a good idea to plan carefully for your given deployment scenario. For example, today if you implement a Windows Azure virtual network and later choose to add site-to-site VPN connectivity, you will have to delete any virtual machines associated with the virtual network before adding the site-to-site gateway. Also, IP address assignment is handled by DHCP. However, the lease duration is infinite so unless you completely stop (deallocate) a virtual machine the system should retain its assigned IP address for the lifetime of the VM. As such, manually assigning a static IP address to a Windows Azure virtual machine is not necessary, and furthermore it is not supported either.

Here is a link to get you started. [Link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-connect-vms/) another [Link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue is that even though ports are getting assigned the VMs are in different subnets, fixing the Virtual Network is what I need to do.

Comment: You only need to start with one network, but you can give access from one subnet to another by creating a route, here is a link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-udr-overview/

Comment: Thanks so much for the info, I eventually needed to use powershell to change my VMs to point to the new subnet I created.